# Eclipse - Terminate from console without the browser closing?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse, Java, and TestNG for automated testing, and when running my scripts, if I encountered a failure, I'd often times click the terminate button in the console. This would stop the script execution, while leaving the browser window open, allowing me to troubleshoot my scripting issue.  A few days ago I downloaded the latest version of Eclipse, and now when I execute my code and press the terminate button, the browser closes.  How do I change this back to the way it was?

Comment: In the upcoming Eclipse 2021-03 (4.19) on March 17, 2021 there will be an option for that: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.19/platform.php#termination-of-descendants-is-configurable

Comment: Thank you that worked.  Just in case that link dies, here's the steps:  1. Run > Run Configuration.
2. Expand TestNG on the left side.
3. Select your desired TestNG xml file.
4. Click Common tab.
5. Uncheck "Terminate child processes if terminiating the launched process"
6. Click Apply.